# Facebook login error "User is not allowed to see the application."

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

Hi: I have submitted my app to the App Store. I have Facebook login feature in my app. When I try to login to Facebook from devices I have I am able to do it seamlessly. However Apple has rejected my app saying " When we tap the Facebook icon to sign up we are taken to mobile Safari where we receive a message that states :

> User is not allowed to see the application.: The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration.

Not sure how will I be able recreate this issue. I installed my app on 3 different devices and was able to login without any errors. I checked my app setting on Facebook Status and Review section of Facebook and I have enabled my general public. Not sure what else I am missing. I just feel very dejected. Can anyone please help me figure this out? I am using parse as my backend service and logging users using parse Facebook login.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Is the app locked to specific countries or age ranges? Is it still in development mode?

Comment: No it is not locked to any specific country or age range. How do I check if the app is still in Development mode? Under Status and Review I have app is enabled to be viewed by general public.

Comment: The error almost always means that toggle on Status & review is set to 'no', the user is blocked (rare) or there are country / age restrictions on the app (unlikely but not that rare) - are you sure you're using the same app ID in the login code as the app whose settings you're checking? I've seen people confuse dev/QA/prod app IDs often

Comment: I have this problem right now for a test user that a developer user created on an app. Status/review, country and age restrictions are all good and the user isn't blocked. If I find a solution I'll post it here.

Comment: I have this problem a couple of days ago and the issue was on the Apple side. I ask the reviewer how they are generating the user but didn't answer. I end creating a fresh Facebook account and ask they to reproduce the issue with that account, they can't so the review process continue :)

Comment: just got a rejection from apple with this issue, is this a real issue I can fix? or it's an apple issue?

Answer (score 94):

Another reason this will happen is if you are logged in as a test user from a different app than the one you are trying to sign in to. Facebook test users are app-specific.

Sign out of Facebook and back in with a test user from the correct app.

Comment: I had this problem, this was the solution.

Comment: ^^ Same here. Never once had to set the namespace as mentioned in another answer. Just make sure you are not logged in as a test user from another app. We have both staging and production apps in Facebook to test against our servers. Production app test accounts will not work with staging app and vice versa.

Comment: Yes. I had the issue. The point, is that you must create a password for the test user, and log in to FB, then you go to your app and do facebook login. Assuming the app will accept the user, it will works.

Comment: Just had an app rejected by Apple for this as well. I provided them with one of our test users and linked them this answer.

Answer (score 14):

Go to Safari > http://m.facebook.com > logout 
In cases where app sign in with safariviewcontroller, sometimes it contains test user of different app

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using wrong facebook application id in the code. So added the correct id & it worked for me.

Comment: I also had this problem. And later found that the Facebook ID I was using was not the one assigned to the environment I was working on.

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs because Apple testers used the same Facebook test account which was created to test any other app and they did not logged out from that account(forgotten to log out) and that facebook test account doesn't have the permission for the current app in review which is why this issue occurs,

You can follow the given link to replicate the issue by creating an an test account.

http://samwize.com/2014/07/23/error-with-facebook-login-using-test-users/

Steps to create Facebook test account
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users#managetool

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem, and it turned out that the problem app didn't have a namespace set up in the Settings > Basic tab. Creating one is the solution to this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  However, in the interest of helping others with this problem, I've encountered this issue multiple times, and this was never the fix.  All of my apps' namespaces remain blank without any problem at all.  The fix (for me) has always been to ensure that the Test User matches the app I'm working with.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have faced this same issue. Presently Facebook doesn't allow you to login from any Facebook id as you app is in development mode. There are 3 possible solutions that work for me:

1. Use only that id for Facebook Log In Testing with which you are working in Facebook for developer.
2. In Facebook for Developer-> Login to your Account-> Open app->Roles-> Test Users-> Add->Submit-> Edit on newly created random tester account->"Change Name and Password for this Test User"-> Provide a Name and handy password for testing.->Submit.(Use the given random generated mail id and password for testing Facebook login through your app.

3)In Facebook for Developer-> Login to your Account-> Open app->Roles->Roles->Testers->Add Testers->Provide Facebook Id for the user you want to add as tester->Submit

To get Facebook Id for a valid user. Login to Facebook with the Id you want to make as facebook tester in your development process.Then goto profile and in URL of browser you see id=(some_random_number). Copy that Id and paste it into Add Tester section of Developer account. It will be in pending state until the valid user accept the inviation.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar when validating to apple too,
I still don't get it now but for some reason the facebook secret id had been erased from the parse configuration.
You must check that point too

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that was the reason or not but for me this happened only after I signed the application with a release key, so I made the app 'public'. Probably the test users doesn't work for public applications.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem, and the solution is to use the same FB test accounts that was created from the same FB App. So if the App get rejected from App, then you should send to Apple a FB test account with password.

Answer (score 0):

In your chrome or safari. facebook is login with another account.
Firstly logout that account and again try to login with your app login.

Answer (score -1):

my side

I was using wrong facebook application id in the code. So added the correct id & it worked for me.