# Facebook login error - The user is not allowed to see this application

Tags: facebook, authentication, permissions

We were using Facebook login in our game but suddenly we start to receive an error saying "The user is not allowed to see this application", right now only works for our developer accounts that are invited to the facebook developers, and with tester accounts too. But all "normal" users are receiving that error message.
The facebook developer config has not changed, is public, approved and we have accepted the permissions (email,public_profile,user_friends).
Any ideas of what is happening? Any place to make a question directly to facebook developers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960053/facebook-login-error-user-is-not-allowed-to-see-the-application

Comment: Take the app live

Comment: Hi @Airam. I have the exact same issue. Suddenly my app starts to fail on Facebook login. I have filed a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1685857555076927/ I think you will have to do the same. You can link to my bug in order to indicate that it must be a global Facebook thing.

Comment: It is also mentioned on the Facebook developer community support group: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1212763342100511