# Facebook iOS 10 login error :user not allowed to see application

Tags: swift, facebook

I am new to iOS programming and I made an app that was able to connect to Facebook before without any problem. I've enabled keychain sharing and made the app public but last week I started seeing an error message:

> 2017-05-23 17:26:11.130 test[3231:77099] -canOpenURL: failed for URL:
>   "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus
>   error -10814.)"

I've followed all the login steps, but no success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have u checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26788622/4962554) solution?

Comment: there is no way to set a namespace for the app. Last week other similar apps worked fine but this one launched an error